# Storing user input inside int array

Tags: c#, arrays, input, int

I just started learning C# and here is where I got stuck. I need an array similar to the one I made in the code, but with integer data type.
Something like this:

```
int[] answer = new int[a];
for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    answer[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

I got the warning message:

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

What is the easiest way to get user input in an integer data type to be stored inside the array `answer`?

Comment: did you try,  int x = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); ?

Comment: Yes, but I still get the same warning output (Input string was not in a correct format).

Comment: Add the flag c#. I am sure there is such a flag.

Comment: **Read** the exception message. You're not entering a number.

Comment: Can you convert a "hello" to `int`?

Comment: [Looks to be working fine...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pinxym). The error only occurs when a user types a string. You need to do some type checking before adding to to your array

Comment: Are you entering all your integers on the same line maybe?

Comment: Perhaps i should copy some more of the code. There is 
if (array == answer)
and i dont know if this can work. Maybe its making troubles, because else statement is working just fine.

Comment: this part of code is syntactically perfect just the problem is that when the user input any string value it can not be converted to int.

Comment: No matter what I enter, a number or a word, I get FormatException like before.

Comment: Do not change your question into something entirely different. I have rolled back the edits for you. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int[] answer = new int[a];
for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answer[i]);
}
```

This method returns the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent of the number contained in `Console.ReadLine()`, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed. So you don't get that error anymore because it returns zero if the conversion failed.

Comment: It prints exactly the same number that i entered. Your code works, TY.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with SetValue as well as int.tryParse. In this case they both work fine for me.

```
int[] answer = new int[a];
for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    array2.SetValue(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As it is obvious that you have just started learning, you should try to keep your code as simple as possible and you should alway try to do only one thing per line.

A simple example which performs operations with an array and a conversion from Console input:

```
        // get user input from console as a string
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        // parse user input into an integer
        int oneNumber = int.Parse(userInput);

        //how many numbers will you have?
        int amountOfNumbers = 10;

        //declare an array which can hold that many numbers
        int[] numbers = new int[amountOfNumbers];

        //which position to save the userInput number at?
        int positionToSaveAt = 0;

        //assign oneNumber to a particular position inside the array
        numbers[positionToSaveAt] = oneNumber;
```

Comment: Hmm Trying to explain simple operations to the OP apparently derserves a downvote?

Comment: I believe the issue is the fact you're not answering the OP's question, but rewording their code. That was not what they were asking for.